# Search inside NSMutableArray the values which are not inside there

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have two `NSMutableArray`, `horasPosibles` and `arrayCodigos`. I need to save the values from the `horasPosibles` which are not inside the `arrayCodigos`. This is what try to do, but get an error message on the second line that says "Expected".

```
for(NSInteger i=0; i < [horasPosibles count];i++) {
   if ([horasPosibles objectAtIndex:i] in arrayCodigos) {
        NSLog(@"YES!");
    }
    else{
        [codigos addObject:[horasPosibles objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: First `[horasPosibles objectAtIndex:i] in arrayCodigos` is invalid syntax, use `containsObject:` instead, which of course depends on the kind of objects. Second, `NSSet` would be perfect for this situation.

Comment: I try to compare with Strings in the both arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NSSet` you can easily do that.

```
    NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: horasPosibles];
    [intersection minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray: arrayCodigos]];


    codigos = [intersection allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@", codigos);
```

Comment: This is slightly different from the original code, because it removes duplicate elements from the array. That might be relevant or not.

Comment: This solve my problem! Thanks a lot, you not only help me to solve the problem but also make me descover new tipe NSSet! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
for(id obj in horasPosibles)
    {
        if (![arrayCodigos containsObject:obj])
        {
            [codigos addObject:obj];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over array1 & search for it in array2. If it is found, add it to array3 if it does not have it already.

```
for (MyObject* obj in array1)
{ 
     if([array2 containsObject:obj] && ![array3 containsObject:obj])
        [array3 addObject:obj];
}
```

If you array1 does not have duplicate items, you don't need the 2nd check.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([horasPosibles objectAtIndex:i] in arrayCodigos)
```

is wrong syntax and should be

```
if ([arrayCodigos containsObject:[horasPosibles objectAtIndex:i]])
```

But you can **simplify** your complete code to

```
codigos = [horasPosibles mutableCopy];       // make a copy
[codigos removeObjectsInArray:arrayCodigos]; // remove all objects from other array
```

Comment: I try these and also works perfectly! Awesome day, I discover 2 ways to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for(NSInteger i=0; i < [horasPosibles count];i++){
    if ([horasPosibles containsObject:[arrayCodigos objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        NSLog(@"YES!");
    }else{
        [codigos addObject:[horasPosibles objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```